# Transfer ERC20 token issue

Tags: solidity

we are tried to transfer ERC20 token from contract address to wallet address(not owner address). Please let me know how to clear this error. Screenshot to added in this post.

Thanks in Advance

code :-

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {

    string public constant name = "A2";
    string public constant symbol = "At";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;


    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 totalSupply_ = 10 ether;


   constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner]-numTokens;
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}


contract LiquidityPool {

    // ERC20 token state variables
    ERC20Basic public  token1;
    ERC20Basic public  token2;

    // State variables for token reserves
    uint256 public reserve1;
    uint256 public reserve2;


    constructor(address _token1, address _token2){
        token1 =  ERC20Basic(_token1);
        token2 =  ERC20Basic(_token2);
    }

    // State variables for liquidity shares
    uint256 public totalLiquidity;
    mapping(address => uint256) public userLiquidity;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    // Events
    event MintLpToken(
        address indexed _liquidityProvider,
        uint256 _sharesMinted
    );

    event BurnLpToken(
        address indexed _liquidityProvider,
        uint256 _sharesBurned
    );

    // Function to get reserves
    function getReserves()
        public
        view
        returns (uint256 _reserve1, uint256 _reserve2)
    {
        _reserve1 = reserve1;
        _reserve2 = reserve2;
    }

    // Internal function to mint liquidity shares
    function _mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) private {
        userLiquidity[_to] += _amount;
        totalLiquidity += _amount;
    }

    // Internal function to burn liquidity shares
    function _burn(address _from, uint256 _amount) private {
        userLiquidity[_from] -= _amount;
        totalLiquidity -= _amount;
    }

    // Internal function to update liquidity pool reserves
    function _update(uint256 _reserve1, uint256 _reserve2) private {
        reserve1 = _reserve1;
        reserve2 = _reserve2;
    }

    // Function for user to swap tokens
    // NOTE: Could possibly make this into 2 functions for gas saving
    function swapTokens(address _tokenIn, uint256 _amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint256 _amountOut)
    {   

        require(
            _tokenIn == address(token1) || _tokenIn == address(token2),
            "Invalid Token Address"
        );

        // Retrieve the "token in" token
        bool isToken1 = _tokenIn == address(token1);

        (uint256 _reserve1, uint256 _reserve2) = getReserves();

        (
            IERC20 tokenIn,
            IERC20 tokenOut,
            uint256 reserveIn,
            uint256 reserveOut
        ) = isToken1
                ? (token1, token2, _reserve1, _reserve2)
                : (token2, token1, _reserve2, _reserve1);

        // Transfer tokenIn to the liquity pool
        require(_amountIn > 0, "Insufficient Amount");
        tokenIn.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);

        // Calculate tokenIn with fee of 0.2%
        uint256 _amountInWithFee = (_amountIn * 998) / 1000;

        /*
        Calculate tokenOut amount using x * y = k
        > (x + dx) * (y + dy) = k`
        > y - dy = (xy) / (x + dx)
        > dy = y - ((xy) / (x + dx))
        > dy = y * (1 - (x / (x + dx)))
        > dy = y * (((x + dx) / (x + dx)) - (x / (x + dx)))
        > dy = y * (dx / (x + dx))
        ~~~ dy = (y * dx) / (x + dx) ~~~
        */
        _amountOut =
            (reserveOut * _amountInWithFee) /
            (reserveIn + _amountInWithFee);

        require(_amountOut < reserveOut, "Insufficient Liquidity");

        // Transfer tokenOut to the user
        tokenOut.transfer(msg.sender, _amountOut);

        // Update the reserves
        _update(
            token1.balanceOf(address(this)),
            token2.balanceOf(address(this))
        );
    }

    // Function for user to add liquidity
    function addLiquidity( uint256 _amountToken1, uint256 _amountToken2)
        external
        returns (uint256 _liquidityShares)
    {

        require(
            token1.transferFrom( msg.sender,
            address(this),  _amountToken1),
            "Token Transfer Failed"
        );
        require(
            token2.transferFrom( msg.sender,
                address(this), _amountToken2),
            "Token Transfer Failed"
        );

        /*
        Check if the ratio of tokens supplied is proportional
        to reserve ratio to satisfy x * y = k for price to not
        change if both reserves are greater than 0
        */
        (uint256 _reserve1, uint256 _reserve2) = getReserves();

        if (_reserve1 > 0 || _reserve2 > 0) {
            require(
                _amountToken1 * _reserve2 == _amountToken2 * _reserve1,
                "Unbalanced Liquidity Provided"
            );
        }

        /*
        Calculate number of liquidity shares to mint using
        the geometric mean as a measure of liquidity. Increase
        in liquidity is proportional to increase in shares
        minted.
        > S = (dx / x) * TL
        > S = (dy / y) * TL
        NOTE: Amount of liquidity shares minted formula is similar
        to Uniswap V2 formula. For minting liquidity shares, we take
        the minimum of the two values calculated to incentivize depositing
        balanced liquidity.
        */
        uint256 _totalLiquidity = totalLiquidity;

        if (_totalLiquidity == 0) {
            _liquidityShares = sqrt(_amountToken1 * _amountToken2);
        } else {
            _liquidityShares = min(
                ((_amountToken1 * _totalLiquidity) / _reserve1),
                ((_amountToken2 * _totalLiquidity) / _reserve2)
            );
        }

        require(_liquidityShares > 0, "No Liquidity Shares Minted");
        // Mint shares to user
        _mint(msg.sender, _liquidityShares);

        // Update the reserves
        _update(
            token1.balanceOf(address(this)),
            token2.balanceOf(address(this))
        );

        emit MintLpToken(msg.sender , _liquidityShares);
    }

    /*
    Function for user to remove liquidity
    > dx = (S / TL) * x
    > dy = (S / TL) * y
    */
    function removeLiquidity(uint256 _liquidityShares)
        external
        returns (uint256 _amountToken1, uint256 _amountToken2)
    {
        
        require(
            userLiquidity[msg.sender] >= _liquidityShares,
            "Insufficient liquidity shares"
        );
        // Get balance of both tokens
        uint256 token1Balance = token1.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 token2Balance = token2.balanceOf(address(this));

        uint256 _totalLiquidity = totalLiquidity;

        _amountToken1 = (_liquidityShares * token1Balance) / _totalLiquidity;
        _amountToken2 = (_liquidityShares * token2Balance) / _totalLiquidity;

        require(
            _amountToken1 > 0 && _amountToken2 > 0,
            "Insufficient transfer amounts"
        );

        // Burn user liquidity shares
        _burn(msg.sender, _liquidityShares);

        // Update reserves
        _update(token1Balance - _amountToken1, token2Balance - _amountToken2);

        // Transfer tokens to user
        token1.transfer(msg.sender, _amountToken1);
        token2.transfer(msg.sender, _amountToken2);

        emit BurnLpToken(msg.sender, _liquidityShares);
    }

    // Internal function to square root a value from Uniswap V2
    function sqrt(uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
        if (y > 3) {
            z = y;
            uint256 x = y / 2 + 1;
            while (x < z) {
                z = x;
                x = (y / x + x) / 2;
            }
        } else if (y != 0) {
            z = 1;
        }
    }

    // Internal function to find minimum value from Uniswap V2
    function min(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
        z = x < y ? x : y;
    }
}


contract Dex {
    // Owner's address of DEX
    address public immutable owner;
    // Array of liquidity pool addresses
    address[] public liquidityPools;

    // Mapping to get address of liquidity pool with token addresses
    mapping(address => mapping(address => address)) public getLiquidityPool;

    // Event
    event LiquidityPoolCreted(
        address indexed _addressToken1,
        address indexed _addressToken2,
        address indexed _addressLiquidityPool
    );

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createLiquidityPool(address _tokenA, address _tokenB)
        external
        returns (address _liquidityPool)
    {
        (address _token1, address _token2) = _tokenA < _tokenB
            ? (_tokenA, _tokenB)
            : (_tokenB, _tokenA);

        require(_token1 != _token2, "Same Token Addresses");
        require(_token1 != address(0), "Invalid Token Address");
        require(_token2 != address(0), "Invalid Token Address");
        require(
            getLiquidityPool[_token1][_token2] == address(0),
            "Pool Already Exists"
        );

        // Create new liquidity pool
        _liquidityPool = address(new LiquidityPool(_token1, _token2));
        getLiquidityPool[_token1][_token2] = _liquidityPool;
        getLiquidityPool[_token2][_token1] = _liquidityPool;
        // Add new liquidity pool address to state array
        liquidityPools.push(_liquidityPool);

        emit LiquidityPoolCreted(_token1, _token2, _liquidityPool);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its probably more relevant in ethereum stack exchange

Comment: Where is the error screenshot, could the error be added to the post? Most helpful is either the hash of a failed transaction, or the hex data from the transaction that isn't making it on chain along with the chain ID and token address for simulation.